# Thread Safety of Static Variable holding Static Cast

Tags: c++, templates, casting, static, crtp

I am doing this:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base : std::enable_shared_from_this<Base<Derived>>
{
public:
    Base() {};
    
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> cast() const
    {
        static std::shared_ptr<Derived> p_derived = std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(this->shared_from_this());
        return p_derived;
    };
};
```

Q1: Is this wrong? Or can you see any ugly silent stuff? Any other "standard/smart" way to do this?

Q2: Is the function Base::cast thread safe? (Multiple threads calling cast).

Thank you!

Comment: Also sorry, how much am I paying for that shared_from_this call :) ? Is that call thread safe?

Comment: It's very thread safe in that every single call to the function will return the same value add the first call to the function no matter which object you call it on which is presumably not what you want. I don't see any reason to do this at all? Is it for performance? Have you measured this function without the static variable and found it was slow?

Comment: Yes for performance. No I didn't measure it. And I thought each object will have its own "this" and static will be defined for each "instance", I am totally wrong here. What If I take off static, will it be ok I guess?

Comment: Seems like if `cast` is going to be a `const` member of `Base`, it should return a `shared_ptr<const Derived>`